# SSAS 2008 date/time measure partition or dimension last processed?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

Is there a way to tell the last date / time a partition was processed?  I've lots of SSAS databases, with lots of partitions and the automation is not, but will be independently recording when a partition was processed.

Is there an independent way to query and confirm?  I've looked @ system.discover_partition_stat and system.discover_partition_dimension_stat, neither of which answer my question of when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Microsoft.AnalysisServices namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.aspx

Here is an example:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// simply refreshes the partition information from the server, then checks a property.  In testing, this property has been accurate.  Initially, I assumed an unprocessed partition would send back a null datetime.  No, what I've been getting back instead is : 1699-12-30 18:00:00.0000000
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="partition"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DateTime? GetPartitionLastDateProcessed(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Partition partition)
        {
            partition.Refresh();

            return
                (
                    partition.LastProcessed
                );
        }
```